# Confirm correct process to use Weibull regression for reliability analysis

Tags: r, survival, reliability, weibull-distribution

I am new to the field of survival analysis. I am trying to fit a Weibull distribution to predict the reliability of a part. I have information from machines that have that part. On some machines the part breaks and gets repaired and operations continue. On other machines the part never breaks.

I have the start time of the machine, the time the part breaks and the time the machine is last observed in the data below,

`PROD_ID event tstart  tstop
 1:      11  TRUE   0.00  13.24
 2:      11 FALSE  10.01  91.10
 3:      12  TRUE   0.00  93.22
 4:      12 FALSE   2.96  81.49
 5:      16  TRUE   0.00   4.11
 6:      16  TRUE  93.37 131.95
 7:      16  TRUE  89.68 142.03
 8:      16 FALSE  89.55 159.80
 9:      35  TRUE   0.00   3.52
10:      35 FALSE  78.17 158.96
11:      64  TRUE   0.00  71.04
12:      64  TRUE  61.33  82.72
13:      64 FALSE  51.74  68.78
14:     108  TRUE   0.00  47.03
15:     108  TRUE  78.96 171.85
16:     108  TRUE  22.84 115.74
17:     108 FALSE  55.22  64.60
18:     131  TRUE   0.00  91.19
19:     131 FALSE  82.18 137.37
20:     136  TRUE   0.00  59.12`

When I do:

```
require(survival)
event_survival <- with(event_info, Surv(tstart, tstop, event))
survreg(event_survival ~ 1, dist = 'weibull')
```

I get an error

```
Error in survreg(event_survival ~ 1, dist = "weibull") : 
  Invalid survival type
```

Therefore I used the eha package to fit interval data with,

```
require(eha)

reliability <- aftreg(Surv(tstart, tstop, event) ~ 1, dist = "weibull", data = event_info)
```

Could you please confirm whether aftref yields the results I am interested in?

The data:

`structure(list(PROD_ID = c(11, 11, 12, 12, 16, 16, 16, 16, 35, 35, 64, 64, 64, 108, 108, 108, 108, 131, 131, 136), event = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), tstart = c(0, 10.01, 0, 2.96, 0, 93.37, 89.68, 89.55, 0, 78.17, 0, 61.33, 51.74, 0, 78.96, 22.84, 55.22, 0, 82.18, 0), tstop = c(13.24, 91.1, 93.22, 81.49, 4.11, 131.95, 142.03, 159.8, 3.52, 158.96, 71.04, 82.72, 68.78, 47.03, 171.85, 115.74, 64.6, 91.19, 137.37, 59.12)), .Names = c("PROD_ID", "event", "tstart", "tstop"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the zero in the data set. The Weibull distribution cannot fit a zero.